# Passing output parameter to an sp which accepts datatable as a parameter using dapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dapper

Hi I am working on mvc as part of my learning, So I came accross a situation where I have to pass a datatable to the sp, along with the datatable I have to give one output parameter of `int` also of the  type. Currently I am using this code

```
con.Execute("XXXXXXX",
 new { @LoginId = LoginId, @City= City, @RegionCode = RegionCode, @CarList= Cars, @CompCOde = COmp},
 commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Here Cars is a datatable so I want to add an output parameter to this , please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a parameter list with one designated as `ParameterDirection.Output`, then you will be able to read from it with `Get`.

**I made some assumptions with the following example including a an int output parameter (not tested)**

```
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();
            p.Add("@LoginId", LoginId, dbType: DbType.VarNumeric, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            p.Add("@City", City, dbType: DbType.VarNumeric, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            p.Add("@RegionCode", RegionCode, dbType: DbType.VarNumeric, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
            p.Add("@CarList", Cars.AsTableValuedParameter());
            p.Add("@SomeId", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
            con.Execute("XXXXXXX",p,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            int someId = p.Get<int>("@SomeId");
```